# How to pass the pointer of a head to a function in main.cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

When I try to call the DisplayLinkedList function in main, it prints out nothing. How do i correctly pass the head into the DisplayLinkedList function so that it properly prints out the entire linked list?

```
void LinkedList::AppendInTheEnd(int numberToAdd)
{
     NodePtr newNode = new Node;
     newNode->nextNode = NULL;
     newNode->data = numberToAdd;

     if(headNode != NULL)
     {
        currentNode = headNode;
        while(currentNode->nextNode != NULL)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
        }
        currentNode->nextNode = newNode;
     }
     else
     {
         headNode = newNode;
     }
}
void LinkedList::DisplayLinkedList(Node* head)
{

         Node* p;
         p = head;
         cout << "Displaying the list" << p << endl;
         while(p != NULL)
         {
              cout << "Node at " << p << endl;
              cout << " value " << p->data << endl;
              cout << " next: " << p->data << endl;
           }
            p = p->nextNode;
}
int main()
{
   LinkedList::Node* head = NULL;


  LinkedList list;

  list.AppendInTheEnd(9);
  list.AppendInTheEnd(10);

  list.DisplayLinkedList(head);
}
```

Comment: You need to show us a [MCVE].  Maybe the problem is in `AppendInTheEnd`.

Comment: I don't see any connection between `head` and `list`, do you maybe wanted to pass the head of `list`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky i have added the AppendInTheEnd function to the question.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that includes the class definition of `LinkedList`. Show us something we can copy/paste/run on our computers.

Comment: @churill i believe that is what i want to do. If that prints out the list, how do i pass the head of the list?

Comment: @theCarnage the problem is not how to pass the head of the list. There are basically two problems: 1. `head` is never updated, it stays `NULL` forever. 2. The overall design looks wrong. Show a [mcve]  as asked before, then wen can tell what's wrong with the design.

Comment: Either he changes the method that prints to accept no argument and just print the list itself starting from the head or he needs a way to access the list's head node and set it to the main's head variable before passing to DisplayLinkedList.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a design issue here (in addition to what Jabberwocky pointed out). `LinkedList::DisplayLinkedList` is a member function and the name implies, that it prints the contents of the list. E.g.

```
list.DisplayLinkedList();
```

would imply, that it prints the content of `list`.

Then why does it take any parameter? It's a member function, which means it's called on an instance of `LinkedList` and you can access the members of this instance using `this->`. Passing some parameter to print any other list than the current instance just makes not much sense. I suggest the following approach:

```
void LinkedList::DisplayLinkedList()
{
     Node *p = this->headNode;
     cout << "Displaying the list" << p << endl;
     while(p != NULL)
     {
         cout << "Node at " << p << "\n"; // prints the address
         cout << " value " << p->data << "\n";
         cout << " next: " << p->data << "\n"; // p->nextNode maybe?

         p = p->nextNode;
     }
}
```

---

For good practice don't spam `endl` ;)

Comment: You should probably mention that `cout << "Displaying the list" << p << endl;` doesn't make much sense, it will output the value of the pointer which is pretty useless.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know, maybe that's what theCarnage wants, but thanks for the   edit, good catch :)

Comment: @churill thank you for the reply.  I myself, would NOT pass the head in a parameter but instead would do something very similar to what you have.  I actually do not even know why I have to pass the head as a parameter and thats the exact reason why i am posting this.  This was a question I was trying to answer and am implementing it my own way but wanted feedback from others as to how and why we would ever want to pass the head as a param if we are just printing out the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a problem here:

```
     while(p != NULL)
     {
          cout << "Node at " << p << endl;
          cout << " value " << p->data << endl;
          cout << " next: " << p->data << endl;
          p = p->nextNode;   // <------------------+
     }                                             |
                                                   |
     // p = p->nextNode;   // this should be here -|
```

The `p = p->nextNode` must be inside the loop.

The other problem I can see is that `head` is actually never updated. It is initialized once to `NULL`. So when you call `DisplayLinkedList(head)`, head is NULL and obviously nothing will be printed.